# htaccess FilesMatch Regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I found this manipulated htaccess in a hacked wordpress installation:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!1555206972)\.php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

but I'm not sure what this is good for. It's a negative lookbehind, that's how much I've figured out so far. But the real function is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed it is negative lookbehind regex.

This regex:

```
(?<!1555206972)\.php$
```

Will match all filenames ending with `.php` except if filename ends with `1555206972.php`.

These directives are blocking all requests for `*.php` files except `1555206972.php` file.

Comment: One question: Assuming there is a directive in a higher directory that prevents PHP from running in the same directory, can I run this file anyway?

Comment: Yes this .htaccess will override a parent directory's .htaccess directive.